# A slightly short "What Am I" Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I live on a 010100101010,  three houses down from Mr Bob Fisher

When larger, I am the most popular “pier”

What am I?

Hint:

> Note that this hint has one word that starts with "N".

Comment: All I got is that 010100101010 is binary, translating to hex gives 52A. 52A is one of the primary contacts on a PCB... But I think I am way off :P

Answer (score 1):

Are you -

> Robot

live on a 010100101010

> Robot deals with Digital data

Mr Bob Fisher

> Related to AI when searched in google.

larger, I am the most popular “pier”

> Big Robots look like "pillars" may be

Comment: Nope. Good guess though

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> a rook?

three houses down from Mr Bob Fisher

> A misspelling of Bobby Fischer, the chess champion, who could be the "king of chess"?  Three spots over from the king.

the most popular “pier”

> A synonym for column, which is like a rook?

Comment: Nope. How does this include the hint?